# getChildHtml('info_tabs') ?> printed on product page

Tags: upgrade, ce-1.8.1.0, magento-1.9.3.2

I'm new to Magento. I have just upgraded from 1.8.1.0 to 1.9.3.2. On my product page I get `getChildHtml('info_tabs') ?>` printed out below our *add to cart*-button. See screenshot below (I have blurred some product information and the language is Swedish for you who wonder :)).

I get no errors in my Apache error log, nor in `var/log/system.log`. I have no idea how to proceed since I am new to Magento development.

[image]

Comment: check your `catalog/product/view.phtml` it looks like `<?php echo $this->` is missing before `getChildHtml('info_tabs')`

Comment: `$ grep -r "getChildHtml('info_tabs')`
`app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml:                           <?//php echo $this->getChildHtml('info_tabs') ?>`
`app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/catalog/product/view.phtml:        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('info_tabs') ?>`
`app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml:<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('info_tabs') ?>`

Comment: Ok, so now I feel my Magento knowledge is really limited... I found three different layout files where this `info_tabs` is included. The one in `mytheme` clearly outcomments that line. Any thoughts on this @JaiminSutariya?

Comment: Could this problem be related to PHP 5.6? I upgraded from PHP 5.4...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with help from @JaiminSutariya, thanks!

The problem was related to PHP comments. Before, I had this line in my `catalog/product/view.pthml`:

```
<?//php echo $this->getChildHtml('info_tabs') ?>
```

which gave the following HTML:

```
<!--?//php echo $this--->
getChildHtml('info_tabs') ?>
```

Changing the PHP line to the following solved the problem:

```
<?php /* echo $this->getChildHtml('info_tabs') */ ?>
```

This must be due to the upgrade from PHP 5.4 to 5.6 which I also did when upgrading to 1.9.3.2.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the upgrade. It's just a mistake smbd made when placing the // (comment-out line) in the wrong place.

Comment: But the exact same code worked before the upgrade...